# 'Diagonalization' of Jordan block

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

We know the Jordan block 
$$J = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda & 1 & & \\
 & \lambda & \ddots & \\
 & & \ddots & 1\\
 & & & \lambda       
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Prove that there exists an invertible $\bf{S}$ such that
$$\bf{SJS^{-1}} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \lambda & \varepsilon & & \\
 & \lambda & \ddots & \\
 & & \ddots & \varepsilon\\
 & & & \lambda       
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
with any nonzero $\varepsilon$.

I have no idea how to construct the $\bf{S}$, or how to 'diagonalize' the Jordan block. Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As always: Start with a 2×2 matrix. Then try 3×3. You should see a pattern.

Comment: The Jordan block can't be diagonalised (that's why we talk about Jordan blocks in the first place).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yep, I made a mistake. I would edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take$$S=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&\varepsilon^{-1}&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&\varepsilon^{-2}&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&\varepsilon^{-(n-1)}\end{bmatrix}$$(where $n$ is such that $J$ is a $n\times n$ matrix). Then$$SJS^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda&\varepsilon&0&\cdots&0\\0&\lambda&\varepsilon&\cdots&0\\0&0&\lambda&\cdots&0\\\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&\lambda\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: If OP asks "give me some hints", I think it's better not to answer with a complete solution. "Try with a diagonal $S$" would have been a better answer in my view.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni If I had thought about that suggestion, perhaps that I would have provided it. But what happens quite often when I provide just a hint is what happend [here today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2598212/how-can-i-find-operatornameimt-and-operatornamekert); someone else provides a complete answer after me and my answer is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

By Jordan normal form theorem, if $A\in k^{n\times n}$ is triangulable and $B\in k^{n\times n}$, then $A$ and $B$ are similar if and only if $\dim\ker (A-\lambda I)^m=\dim\ker (B-\lambda I)^m$ for all $m\in\Bbb N$ and for all $\lambda\in k$.

This is easily applied to this case, because $J_\varepsilon-\lambda I=\varepsilon(J-\lambda I)$, while $J_\varepsilon-\mu I$ and $J-\mu I$ are both invertible when $\mu\ne \lambda$.

The same lemma and some calculations prove that an upper-triangular matrix is similar to $J$ if and only if, for all $i$, $a_{i,i}=\lambda$ and $a_{i,i+1}\ne 0$.