# How can i find $\operatorname{Im}(T)$ and $\operatorname{Ker}(T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In given Linear Transformation $T:\mathbb{R}_{2}[x] \to \mathbb{R}_{2}[x]$ so that:
$$T(p_{1})=-2x^2-4x+5$$
$$T(p_{2})=10x^2-9x-5$$
$$T(p_{3})=-x^2-3x+2$$

While:
$$p_{1}=x^2+4x+3$$
$$p_{2}=-3x^2-x+4$$
$$p_{3}=-3x^2-3x-5$$

How can i find $\text{Im}(T)$ and $\text{Ker}(T)$?

Comment: Write (a) the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $[p_1,p_2,p_3]$ and $[1,x,x^2]$ (b) the matrix of $[p_1,p_2,p_3]$ w.r.t $[1,x,x^2]$. Deduce  the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. $[p_1,p_2,p_3]$ (and itself), then compute $Im(T),Ker(T)$ by your favorite method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

$T(p_2-p_3)=T(2x+9)=11x^2-6x-7$

$T(3p_1+p_2)=T(11x+13)=4x^2-21x+10$

$T(6p_1+2p_2-11p_2+11p_3)=T(26-99)=8x^2-42x+20-11(11x^2-6x-7)$

Thus you can find $T(1)$, by dividing by $-73$.
Then with the same idea you can find $T(x)$ and $T(x^2)$. I let you complete the computations that are not particularly fun.

This allows you to write $T(P)$ for any $P \in \mathbb{R}_2[X]$, and therefore to find $Ker(T)$ and $Im(T)$.

Answer (score 0):

The image of $T$ is the set of all linear combinations of $T(p_1)$, $T(p_2)$, and $T(p_3)$. And you can determine $\ker T$ solving the equation $T(\alpha_1p_1+\alpha_2p_2+\alpha_3p_3)=0$.